# Python IO Unhashable list Regex

Tags: python, regex, io, pandas

I have a list that I loaded from a txt file and ran some code to match data. But I get  `TypeError: Unhashable list` I looked at several answers on Stack and can't find out where I passed a list into the loop. I am guessing it has something to do with df because it works when I am not using data that was loaded in.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

#Capture tester
df = pd.read_csv('patterntest.txt', header=None, dtype=str)
df.columns = ['names']
df['status']=''

patterns=['(?i)(C|F|L)at', 'Dog']


for i in xrange(len(patterns)):
    df.loc[df.names.str.match(patterns[i]),'status'] = 'CAPTURED'

print df
```

I do not see where I passed a list into the `for` loop either.

All the file 'patterntest.txt' has inside is just some text like:

```
dog
cat
mouse
frog
fox
canis sp
```

Here is my input

```
import pandas as pd
import re

#Capture tester
df = pd.read_csv('patterntest.txt', header=None, dtype=str)
df.columns = ['names']
df['status']=''

patterns=['(?i)(C|H|L)at', 'Dog']




##
##for i in xrange(len(patterns)):
##    df.loc[df.names.str.match(patterns[i]),'status'] = 'CAPTURED'

print df.names.str.match(patterns[0])
print df.names.str.match(patterns[1])
```

Output:

```
>>> 
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py:350: UserWarning: In future versions of pandas, match will change to always return a bool indexer.
  " always return a bool indexer.""", UserWarning)
0      []
1    (C,)
2      []
3      []
4      []
5      []
Name: names, dtype: object
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: names, dtype: bool
```

I tested both patterns to see if it is the regex and it seems like it might be.

**Update**: Confirmed it is a regex problem changed out Regex and it works fine.

```
df = pd.read_csv('patterntest.txt', header=None, dtype=str)
df.columns = ['names']
df['status']=''

patterns=['Cat', 'Dog']



for i in xrange(len(patterns)):
    df.loc[df.names.str.match(patterns[i]),'status'] = 'CAPTURED'
```

So is there a way to solve this?

Comment: What does `df.names.str.match(patterns[i])` return?

Comment: @NPE If I put the pattern maually in it returns a bunch of []. If I put `pattern[1]` it returns a boolean value.

Comment: @NPE I think it is some thing with the format of the dataframe because `df.names.str.match(patterns[1])` returns an array of `True/False` values. But then when you put that into `df[df.names.str.match(patterns[1])]` you get brackets `[]`

Comment: Can you give a small example which demonstrates this?

Comment: @AndyHayden Yes I will

Comment: @AndyHayden The pattern does not seem to be process with regex

Comment: @AndyHayden How do I check? I am using Python 2.7

Comment: print pd.version.version

Comment: @AndyHayden Oh you mean Pandas Yes it is 0.13.0

Comment: I think this behaviour is deprecated then changing, it'll return bool if there is no groups (and the things in brackets are considered groups... :s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain the behavior of the depreciated (in 0.13) match: It now returns bool **unless** there are groups in the pattern *(here the parenthesis are groups, hence C is returned in one row)*... :s

You should use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains.html) rather than [`str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.match.html)*:

```
In [11]: s.str.contains('(?i)(C|H|L)at', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
Out[11]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: name, dtype: bool

In [12]: s.str.contains('Dog', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
Out[12]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: name, dtype: bool
```

To check it is the *entire* string, you should use the start (`^`) and end (`$`) regex:

```
In [13]: s.str.contains('^Dog$', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
Out[13]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: name, dtype: bool
```

* *Note: [match is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.match.html) in 0.13.*

Comment: `str.contains` works but it also picks up unwanted data(ie: strings such as 'African Wild Dog', 'Super Cat')

Comment: @user3084006 use the special start and end regex e.g. `'^Dog$'`.